# how i can get limit view in grid-pane with row and column when i press next or previous

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

i have project for category and subcategory i'm using gridpane for showing the category but i have small issue when i press next or previous i need just give limit view for example 5 category then when i press next or previous give me 5 category now is give me when i press next/previous sometime 6 sometime 3 sometime 5

database table in mysql :

```
CREATE TABLE mr_groupshow (
gr_srn INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
gr_name1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gr_name2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gr_status boolean,
gr_create_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

this is my FXML Code :

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor_groups" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="331.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0d6d7c; -fx-border-color: #0d6d7c;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="285.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane fx:id="grid_groups" alignment="CENTER" gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="1.0" layoutX="44.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="96.0" style="-fx-background-color: b9e4e0;" styleClass="my-grid-groups" stylesheets="@mainmenu.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="43.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="44.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                        <HBox layoutX="45.0" layoutY="6.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="44.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="44.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
                        <Button fx:id="next_g" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="484.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="43.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2a97a1;" styleClass="addBobOk" stylesheets="@mainmenu.css" text="N" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow color="#0eb0f5" />
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="previous_g" focusTraversable="false" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="43.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2a97a1;" styleClass="addBobOk" stylesheets="@mainmenu.css" text="P" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <effect>
                              <DropShadow color="#0eb0f5" />
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
```

and this is code for get data from mysql :

```
//connect DB to show groups in gridgroups
    public int groupsview(int nw1, int pw1) {

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        grid_groups.getChildren().clear();

        try {

            // Statement
            myStmt = con.createStatement();
            // SQL query
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from mr_groupshow where gr_status=0 limit " + nw1 + "," + pw1 + "");
            // Result processing

            while (rs.next()) {
//                String itm = rs.getString("it.itemname_1");
                String grno = rs.getString("gr_srn");
                String grp = rs.getString("gr_name2");
                String img = rs.getString("gr_image");
                if (col > 4) {
                    row++;
                    col = 0;
                }
                imageviewgroups(col, row, img);
                gr_groups(col, row, grp);
                gr_groups_id(col, row, grno);
                col++;

            }
            System.out.println(myStmt);
            //End of Code
            //}
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }

        return pw1;

    }
```

and count for get count category from database :

```
//group count from db
    public int groupcount1(int count) {
        count = 0;
        try {
            // Statement
            myStmt = con.createStatement();
            // SQL query
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from mr_groupshow where gr_status = 0 ");
            rs.last();
            count = rs.getRow();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

        return count;

    }
```

and code for press next/previous button :

```
public void nextprevous(){
     previous_g.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                int nc = 0;
                int nc1 = groupcount1(nc++);
                r2 = r1;
                r2 = 0;
                if (r1++ > 0) {
                    grid_groups.getChildren().remove(r2, r1);
                    groupsview(r2, r1);
                }

            });
            next_g.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                int nc = 0;
                int nc1 = groupcount1(nc);
                r1 = r2;
                r2 = r1;
                if (r2++ < nc1++) {
                    grid_groups.getChildren().remove(r1, r2);
                    groupsview(r1, r2);

                }

            });
}
```

this is picuter of my category in my project :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11dPr.png)

Comment: I am a bit unclear with your question. Can you rephrase your question.

Comment: hi dear @SaiDandem i think is clear question i need but fix limit when i click to next button or previous button